# Update a table with values from another table (which has 3 keys and only 2 keys found in the other matching table)

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge

Table  1 (Key fields - Id, Account)

- Id, Account, SalesRepID

Table 2 (Key fields - Id, Account, Code)

- Id, Account, Sequence,SalesRepID

Table1.SalesRepID should be updated with Table2.SalesRepID when Table2.Sequence = 1. (There are 10 sequences and each has a SalesRedID).

```
UPDATE Table1 SET SalesRepID = 
(select SalesRepID from Table2 
where Table1.ID = Table2.ID and 
Table1.Account = Table2.PatientAccount and Table2.Sequence = 1)
```

This throws an error -

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Please let me know what should be fixed in the update statement?
Should a MERGE be used?

Comment: If there is more than one record for which `Table2.Sequence = 1`, then your update logic by itself makes no sense, because it isn't clear _which_ value you want to use in the update.  For best results, add some sample data to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You'll better using JOIN instead.

```
UPDATE t1 
SET 
    t1.SalesRepID = t2.SalesRepID
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID AND t1.Account = t2.PatientAccount AND t2.Sequence = 1
```

It'll be much easier to maintain and expand.

Answer (score 0):

What part of the error do you not understand?

You have multiple rows in `Table2` that match the conditions.  You can find these using:

```
select id, PatientAccount
from table2
where sequence = 1
group by id, PatientAccount
having count(*) > 1;
```

You can get your query to work using:

```
update Table1 
    set SalesRepID = (select top (1) t2.SalesRepID
                      from Table2 t2
                      where Table1.ID = t2.ID and 
                            Table1.Account = t2.PatientAccount and
                            t2.Sequence = 1
                     );
```

However, this is a brute force approach/hack.  You really need to figure out what is wrong with the data (that is, why you think the subquery should return one row when it really returns multiple rows).